# "Children could not be evaluated" in EF 6

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6

Recently, I updated a project to Entity Framework 6 (VS2013). But, when I'm trying expand the results of a query on the debug mode (using breakpoints) this message appears: "Children could not be evaluated"

The query, is this:

```
using ( SystemDataContext objDB = new SystemDataContext() )
    var obj = (
        from x in objDB.Functionality
        orderby x.ID
        select new
        {
            ID = x.ID,
        }
    );
```

[image: Error]

What is happening?

Comment: It looks like you are missing some code from that code block. Where do you reference the linq-to-entities query?

Comment: Is just a example. The code is right because it fills a control in my page.

Comment: I resolved the problem adding the obj to the Watch Window of VS, calling the ToList() method and clicking on the "Force Evaluation" button (on the Watch itself).

Comment: I have the same problem like you and I couldn't found the answer

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error using the generic repository pattern,but during the implementation of repository pattern in GetAll() method, I used .Tolist().then its work fine.

```
    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _dbSet.AsEnumerable<T>().ToList();
    }
```